# Managed disks in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-disk

I want to know restrictions in  Azure Managed disks. Which is asked in Interview.

what are the restrictions for customers using managed disks in Azure

Comment: Why are you asking us when [the answers are in Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-types)?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Managed Disks are managed by Microsoft Azure and you don't need any storage account while created new disk. Since the storage account is managed by Azure you do not have full control of the disks that are being created that is one limitation that we have with managed disks. There are no other specific restrictions as such with managed disks. They are widely used in Azure and is highly recommended.

Adding more..
Managed disks brought new experience and features to Azure VM storage that permits better controlling the VM storage. Azure recommends using managed disks, even if the ‘Pay as you consume’ model is not adopted there. But the features and the simplicity is worth the ‘little’ difference we can see with pricing.

There is also nice practical differences summary [here](https://buildwindows.wordpress.com/2017/05/31/azure-managed-vs-unmanaged-disks-the-choice/) between managed and unmanaged disks that might come handy as you will be able to understand what is useful in various configuration needs.

Happy Learning!